# How to apply magento discount on custom fee in Magento2.2.X

Tags: checkout, orders, discount, totals, extrafee

I have created a custom module that will add custom fee on order and show it everywhere in cart, checkout, order details etc, But When I applied magento discount it will not include this custom fee amount for discount tobe applied on.

Suggest what changes I need to done for this.

Comment: Is this custom fee, some kind of Tax ? Can you please post a screenshot of your checkout page, so all can have a better idea ?

Comment: @MGento, It is a kind of surcharge

Comment: so all of your products will be having this surcharge ?

Comment: @MGento Its can be for all, for some or Can be order wise.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you set the surcharge with Totals ?

Comment: @MGento, I am using an extension for this. Which add Surcharge fee